# Related Product

Tags: related-products, magento1.9.2.4

i am New In Magento. I want to add related product tab in my product page after review tab. i am working in RWD 1 column default theme can any one help.

I have already add related product in Product Information Page But the related product tab not appear in product page. Magento 1.9.2.4

[image]

Comment: Could you show us how you've done it in the admin?

Comment: first of all i have add related product in product information page 

LIke i have 10 type different watches so i have add all watches in product information page via select any oprion

Comment: http://ulogin.co.uk/    see this is website URL first 3 product is watch

Comment: open this link

http://logintech.co.uk/loginspprt/coveredbuckles/desc/relat.jpg

please can you provide me solution asap i am trying it last 24 hours
and my mind was just going blast....

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following in your `local.xml` file:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related.tab" as="related_products_tab" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml">
            <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Related Products</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <remove name="catalog.product.related"/>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: i have already try it. its not working for me.
the uploaded path is : app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout

Answer (score 0):

Use this free extension. Hope it will help you. Also if you are a developer then try to understand what they are doing.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/free-products-tabs-extension-for-magento.html

Comment: I have added this extension and the result is look like this please open the link : http://logintech.co.uk/loginspprt/coveredbuckles/desc/easytab.jpg
Not Coming any tab

Comment: Go to your frontend now. You can see that related product tab is there

Comment: For your knowledge you can see a new menu on admin header named **template master**. You can edit all tabs from here. Please let me know the result

Comment: yeah its inside system / Configuration / TEMPLATES-MASTER / Easy Tabs

But there was no any tab inside easy tabs 

http://logintech.co.uk/loginspprt/coveredbuckles/desc/easytab.jpg
OPen the link for screen shot

Comment: Please see there is another header link just inside of sell On Ebay .  Check this screenshot http://imgur.com/jGNQc9F

Comment: Not any header inside sell on ebay if you like to see my screen then share your skype id i would share screen ..

Comment: Do you check the screenshot i send to you??? this is the screenshot which you give me. I also red marked that.. check this http://imgur.com/jGNQc9F

Comment: If it help then vote my answer

Comment: yeah sure !!

one more thing now how can i get this tab in my product page its come automatically in my product page ?

Comment: Yes. It will automatically come. make sure you flushed cache

Comment: ok let me try and how can i vote your answer?

Comment: click on the upper arrow inside my answer

Comment: i have done it but i done have enough reputation for that once i earned 15 reputation it will be display

Comment: Now you got reputation.

Comment: i have only 6 reputation my friend

i have flush Magento cache  but related product tab not coming...